# SQL SERVER - Alterar registros diferentes em um campo baseado em outro campo

Tags: sql, sql-server, microsoft

Olá, Estou tentando alterar uma coluna no SQL SERVER (Query) baseado em outra coluna. Tenho registros divergentes de razão social para o mesmo CNPJ, sendo assim desejo que para o mesmo CNPJ somente um nome de razão social seja considerado na consulta, independente de qual for o nome.

**Exemplo do Problema**

[image: Exemplo do Problema]

**Tentativas Realizadas**

- SubQueries
- Joins com Distinct

```sql
    SELECT CODIGO_PARCEIRO, NOME_PARCEIRO
    FROM VW_DM_REPORTS
    WHERE CODIGO_PARCEIRO =  '27179922000164'
```

**Solução**

[image: Solução desejada]

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Sem a estrutura das suas tabelas e dados de exemplo fica bem difícil opinar na resolução do seu problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CODIGO_PARCEIRO, MAX(NOME_PARCEIRO) AS NOME_PARCEIRO
  FROM VW_DM_REPORTS
 WHERE CODIGO_PARCEIRO =  '27179922000164'
 GROUP BY CODIGO_PARCEIRO
```

---

> [**`MAX`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187751(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Retorna o valor máximo na expressão.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Uma possibilidade é usar a função analítica [`FIRST_VALUE()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) para retorna o primeiro valor em um conjunto ordenado de valores particionados pelos dados de uma coluna especificada.

*Conjunto de dados para o teste:*

```
CREATE TABLE VW_DM_REPORTS(
  CODIGO_PARCEIRO VARCHAR(14), NOME_PARCEIRO VARCHAR(30)
);
  
INSERT INTO VW_DM_REPORTS VALUES (N'27179922000164', N'LUCENA TELECOM');
INSERT INTO VW_DM_REPORTS VALUES (N'27179922000164', N'LUCENA TELECOM');
INSERT INTO VW_DM_REPORTS VALUES (N'02570688000170', N'BRASIL TELECOM S/A');
INSERT INTO VW_DM_REPORTS VALUES (N'27179922000164', N'LUCENA TELECOM EIRELI');
INSERT INTO VW_DM_REPORTS VALUES (N'27179922000164', N'LUCENA TELECOM EIRELI');
INSERT INTO VW_DM_REPORTS VALUES (N'27179922000164', N'LUCENA TELECOM EIRELI');
INSERT INTO VW_DM_REPORTS VALUES (N'27179922000164', N'LUCENA TELECOM');
INSERT INTO VW_DM_REPORTS VALUES (N'02570688000170', N'BRASIL TELECOM');
```

*Exemplo 1:*

```
SELECT CODIGO_PARCEIRO, 
       FIRST_VALUE(NOME_PARCEIRO) OVER (
         PARTITION BY CODIGO_PARCEIRO
         ORDER BY NOME_PARCEIRO ASC
       )
FROM VW_DM_REPORTS
WHERE CODIGO_PARCEIRO = '27179922000164'
```

[image: Resultado do exemplo1]

*Exemplo 2:*

```
SELECT CODIGO_PARCEIRO, 
       FIRST_VALUE(NOME_PARCEIRO) OVER (
         PARTITION BY CODIGO_PARCEIRO
         ORDER BY NOME_PARCEIRO ASC
       )
FROM VW_DM_REPORTS
```

[image: Resultado do exemplo2]